# What criteria should one used to determine if Dependency Injection Framework should be used?

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Compared to implementing dependency injection by hand, using a framework seems like a heavyweight approach.

What criteria should one used in order to determine if Dependency Injection Framework should be used?Can you advise on the criteria used to decide if a DI framework should be adopted for a project.

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I am asking for a set of criteria.  The post you mentioned seems very loose - the best answer is to use it for unit test, which is not a good or complete answer.

Comment: See: [When to use a DI Container by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/).